# How to use NSS 3.30 by chromedriver on linux Travis-ci?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, travis-ci, libnss3

I want use new format of chromedriver (115+) on Travis-ci, but I have this error:

```
/home/travis/build/xxxx/xxxx/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so:
version `NSS_3.30' not found
(required by /home/travis/build/xxxx/xxxx/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver)
```

I try add `- sudo apt-get install libnss3` in `before_script` of travis-ci file but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgrade from `dist: trusty` to `dist: xenial`